# xcode 9 crashes when opening storyboard created with xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode9, macos-high-sierra

xcode 9 crashes 100% of the time while opening a storyboard created by xcode 8 on high sierra.
This happens on every project.

Error message was : 
"There can only be one document registered with a given URL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for me was to :

- Cleaning build folder
- Clean, delete derived data
- Delete saved state
- Reboot with reopening windows
- Create new single view application
- Open storyboard.

Now you should be able to open your storyboards again

Answer (score 1):

Create a new single view application, open the storyboard there, and then go back to your original project and it should work.